# Is there a simple wait / sleep function in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, wait, sleep

I'm making a game and I need to change a UI element timely like this:

```
t.text = "Hello!";
wait_function(3);
t.text = "I will be your guide.";
wait_function("TO DEATH!");
```

Is there a simple easily callable wait function in Unity C#?

Comment: In Unity you must not stop the main thread to wait for something. It will freeze the entire app. One option is to use a coroutine for this. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html

Comment: depending on the version of unity you can use awaitables, which work well, however, there are many ways to do some form of count down, Ninja has said coroutines, they work, other ways include invokes or timers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Coroutine or an IEnumerator function and in it, you can use the command WaitForSeconds(int) to have a wait function.

Like this...

```
void Start(){
    StartCoroutine(ExampleCoroutine());
}

IEnumerator ExampleCoroutine() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
}
```

[Link to the document](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Invoke functions.
and also there's a new feature called awaitable functions that is added recently to unity which solve the timing problems of using async/await in unity. one the awaitable functions is WaitForSecondsAsync.

more about awaitable: https://docs.unity3d.com/2023.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Awaitable.html

about the function: https://docs.unity3d.com/2023.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Awaitable.WaitForSecondsAsync.html

there is also a youtube video about it that made by Tarodev: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X9Dtb_4os1o